# Why the composition of two functors is a bifunctor？

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I just know that the composition of two functors is in the same way as functions，but I can't understand how it can be a bifunctor.[image]

Comment: Are you sure it says "composite $GF$" and not "composition of $F$ with $G$"? It is the operation of forming $GF$ from $G$ and $F$ that could be considered to be a bifunctor, not the result $GF$ of applying that operation (which is simply a functor from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf C''$).

Comment: As it is a translation of the French version,I think maybe it mistranslate the original meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote is stating that $$\circ: \mathrm{C}''^{\mathrm{C}'} \times \mathrm{C}'^\mathrm{C}  \to \mathrm{C}''^\mathrm{C}$$ is a bifunctor: that is, it is a functor whose domain is a product of categories.